# How to dynamically allocate a multidimensional array in Visual Studio 2017 in C?

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

I started to use [the method taught by Lundin here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) to dynamically allocate multidimensional arrays in `C` in `Codeblocks`. Now I switched to `Visual Studio 2017` and I can't do it anymore, and I don't know how to do it. I have read many questions and answers and I google searched for the answer, but I still can't do it. Please help me to dynamically allocate a 2D array in Visual Studio. Here is the my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
void arr_alloc(size_t x, size_t y, int(**aptr)[x][y])
{
    *aptr = malloc(sizeof(int[x][y])); // allocate a true 2D array
    assert(*aptr != NULL);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5;

    int(*aptr)[n][n];
    arr_alloc(n, n, &aptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I will add a screenshot with the error messages and the code.[image]

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't support C99, and by extension VLA's or pointers to them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I write `C` programs like that. I am new, but as I understood this is the way it's done in `Visual Studio`. I am pretty sure that is not the problem because I wrote many programs like this.

Comment: @StoryTeller is correct. Use a modern, standard compliant compiler, not some outdated not even C99 compliant rubbish.

Comment: @StoryTeller As I know `for(int i; i < n; i++)` is a C99 feature and I can write this in `Visual Studio` and I can't write it in `Codeblocks`.

Comment: And don't post images of text!

Comment: Neither VisualStudio nor Code::Blocks are compilers!

Comment: @Olaf I did that so people can see what line are errors refer.

Comment: @Timʘtei - Compilers supported that as an extension long before C99 existed. The state of affairs is that Microsoft provides only a C++ compiler, and their C fronted is mostly C89.

Comment: So what software does "real life" programmers and engineers use to write `C` code?

Comment: @Timʘtei yes, it is correct that you can do variable declarations within the for-body; the Microsoft "C" compiler has supported some C99 features for some time...

Comment: @Timʘtei - You can try Clang-CL. Not sure if it will allows C99 features (some rubbish about compatibility with VC++), but worth a shot.

Comment: The Visual C++ compiler supports much of C99, but most notably only the parts of C99 that is also part of the ISO C++ standard. Variable-length arrays are not part of C++ and so not supported in Visual Studio.

Comment: This programmer avoids Windows altogether like plague... Usually the default compiler *pre-installed* in the operating system in non-Windows OSes is better than that which you purposefully need to install into Windows.

Comment: gcc or clang are a good pick. Not sure about clang, but gcc also supports a lot of embedded CPUs.

Comment: Need to use good old pointer arithmetic. So malloc an int * arr to size sizeof(int) * xdim * ydim and access the int as arr[x + y*xdim]